# How can I bring a layer to the back in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers

I want to bring to the back (wrap behind) a layer in QGIS and I have no idea how. Anybody knows how?

the layers I want to bring to the front

[image]

if I select every layer, the big one pops over

[image]

Comment: ....Thats are all possible ways to change the layerorder, but how to save the layerorder? Everytime after reset and load the shapes again the changed layerorder is gone:-( How can we save the Layerorder?

Comment: Don't you save your project file? Layer order is stored in it. There is no way for QGIS to know how to order layers when you simply import them in a project.

Answer (score 11):

Select the layer, drag it to the bottom

Answer (score 10):

JGH described the most straightforward way to do this. I would add a method if you, for example, have data in groups you don't want to change the order.

- Right-click on any free space on a panel or menu
- Choose the Option "Layer Order Panel"
- In the new window check the "Control rendering order"
- Drag and drop the layers around

The gif shows the summarized workflow:
[image: Gif which shows the workflow]

Answer (score 2):

@JGH and @LaughU seems to cover it,

Perhaps think of the layer order panel like a stack of papers or transparency sheets for an Overhead Projector.
The first layer in the Layer Panel list (first sheet), appears on the map first, anything below it appears on the map after it, as if you add sheets on top of the first sheet on the projector.  You don't need to have Control rendering order ticked.

**Top Layer** - Appears on Map First

**Bottom Layer** - Appears on Map Last

[image]

@LaughU answer explains how one can reorder layers in the Panel list but fix the order in which they appear.